# Minimum number of swaps to convert a string to palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm

We are given a string and we have to find out the minimum number of swaps to convert it into a palindrome.

```
Ex-
Given string: ntiin
Palindrome: nitin
Minimum number of swaps: 1
```

If it is not possible to convert it into a palindrome, return `-1`.

I am unable to think of any approach except `brute force`. We can check on the first and last characters, if they are equal, we check for the smaller substring, and then apply brute force on it. But this will be of a very high complexity, and I feel this question can be solved in another way. Maybe `dynamic programming`. How to approach it?

Comment: Just spitballing here, but if you have an even number of copies of some letter, you know you're going to need to get them in opposite positions. You could think of the middle of the word as being index 0, the length/2 as the last index, -length/2 as the first. If you have one copy of a letter, you have to get it into the middle. So then the question becomes something more like, is it faster to migrate a letter on the right or left half?

Comment: There could also be many palindrome states.

Comment: What is a “swap”? Is it allowed to swap any two elements, or only adjacent ones?

Comment: @Daniel Lyons I could understand most of the part, but how can we achieve that migration, because if we think of setting one letter in left half at a place closer to the middle one, maybe the one giving optimal solution would be when we set letter in right half closer to it. Not sure tho!

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes there maybe! We have to output for the one we get through minimum swaps. Even in hat case, I think many palindromes can be possible.

Comment: @kkm We can swap any two elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you could check if the string can be converted to a palindrome.

Just have an array of letters (26 chars if all letters are latin lowercase), and count the number of each letter in the input string.

If string length is even, all letters counts should be even.
If string length is odd, all letters counts should be even except one.

This first pass in O(n) will already treat all -1 cases.

If the string length is odd, start by moving the element with odd count to the middle.

Then you can apply following procedure:

Build a weighted graph with the following logic for an input string `S` of length `N`:

For every element from index `0` to `N/2-1`:
- If symmetric element S[N-index-1] is same continue
- If different, create edge between the 2 characters (alphabetic order), or increment weight of an existing one

The idea is that when a weight is even you can do a 'good swap' by forming two pairs in one swap.
When weight is odd, you cannot place two pairs in one swap, your swaps need to form a cycle

```
1. For instance "a    b   a   b"
One edge between a,b of weight 2:
a - b (2)

Return 1

2. For instance: "a     b    c   b    a    c"
a - c (1)
b - a (1)
c - b (1)

See the cycle: a - b, b - c, c - a

After a swap of a,c you get:

a - a (1)
b - c (1)
c - b (1)   

Which is after ignoring first one and merge 2 & 3: 

c - b (2)

Which is even, you get to the result in one swap

Return 2

3. For instance: "a     b    c   a   b   c"
a - c (2)

One swap and you are good
```

So basically after your graph is generated, add to the result the weight/2 (integer division e.g. 7/3 = 3) of each edge

Plus find the cycles and add to the result length-1 of each cycle

Comment: But does this result in the _minimum_ number of swaps?

Comment: This is not right. "If string length is odd, all letters counts should be odd except one" Example: abcba, the "a" and "b" have counts two which are even not odd. The "c" has count 1

Answer (score 4):

there is the same question as asked!
https://www.codechef.com/problems/ENCD12

I got ac for this solution
https://www.ideone.com/8wF9DT

```
//minimum adjacent swaps to make a string to its palindrome
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool check(string s)
{
    int n=s.length();
    map<char,int> m;
    for(auto i:s)
    {
        m[i]++;
    }
    int cnt=0;
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++)
    {
        if(i->second%2)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if(n%2&&cnt==1){return true;}
    if(!(n%2)&&cnt==0){return true;}
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    while(cin>>a)
    {
        if(a[0]=='0')
        {
            break;
        }
        string s;s=a;
        int n=s.length();
        //first check if
        int cnt=0;
        bool ini=false;
        if(n%2){ini=true;}
        if(check(s))
        {
            for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
            {
                bool fl=false;
                int j=0;
                for(j=n-1-i;j>i;j--)
                {

                    if(s[j]==s[i])
                    {
                        fl=true;
                        for(int k=j;k<n-1-i;k++)
                        {
                            swap(s[k],s[k+1]);
                            cnt++;
//                            cout<<cnt<<endl<<flush;
                        }
//                        cout<<" "<<i<<" "<<cnt<<endl<<flush;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!fl&&ini)
                {
                    for(int k=i;k<n/2;k++)
                    {
                        swap(s[k],s[k+1]);
                        cnt++;

                    }
//                    cout<<cnt<<" "<<i<<" "<<endl<<flush;
                }
            }
            cout<<cnt<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Impossible"<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Technique behind my code is Greedy
first check if palindrome string can exist for the the string and if it can
there would be two cases one is when the string length would be odd then only count of one char has be odd
and if even then no count should be odd
then
from index 0 to n/2-1 do the following
fix this character and search for this char from n-i-1 to i+1
if found then swap from that position (lets say j) to its new position n-i-1
if the string length is odd then every time you encounter a char with no other occurence shift it to n/2th position..

Comment: The two problems are different. In this question, OP mentions that *We can swap any two elements* in the comments whereas the question you are referring to allows for swapping only adjacent characters.

Answer (score 3):

My solution revolves around the palindrome property that first element and last element should match and if their adjacent elements also do not match then its not a palindrome. Keep comparing and swapping till both reach the same element or adjacent elements.

Written solution in java as below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "natinat";
        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        int swap = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = arr.length-1;
        char temp;
        while(i<j){
            if(arr[i] != arr[j]){
                if(arr[i+1] == arr[j]){
                    //swap i and i+1 and increment i, decrement j, swap++
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = temp;

                    i++;j--;
                    swap++;
                } else if(arr[i] == arr[j-1]){
                    //swap j and j-1 and increment i, decrement j, swap++
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1] = temp;

                    i++;j--;
                    swap++;
                } else if(arr[i+1] == arr[j-1] && i+1 != j-1){
                    //swap i and i+1, swap j and j-1 and increment i, decrement j, swap+2
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1] = temp;

                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = temp;

                    i++;j--;
                    swap = swap+2;
                }else{
                    swap = -1;break;
                }       
            } else{
                //increment i, decrement j
                i++;j--;
            }
        }       
        System.out.println("No Of Swaps: "+swap);
    }
```

Comment: Hey! it will not work for the input string "aabb". it should be return 2 according to your algo returning -1

Answer (score 0):

My solution in java for any type of string i.e Binary String, Numbers

```
public int countSwapInPalindrome(String s){
    int length = s.length();
    if (length == 0 || length == 1) return -1;

    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    int start = 0, end = length - 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (start < end) {
        if (str[start] != str[end]){
            boolean isSwapped = false;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++){
                if (str[start] == str[i]){
                    char temp = str[i];
                    str[i] = str[end];
                    str[end] = temp;
                    count++;
                    isSwapped = true;
                    break;
                }else if (str[end] == str[i]){
                    char temp = str[i];
                    str[i] = str[start];
                    str[start] = temp;
                    count++;
                    isSwapped = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isSwapped) return -1;
        }
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    return (s.equals(String.valueOf(str))) ? -1 : count;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int n = s.size(),odd=0;
    vi cnt(26,0);
    unordered_map<int,set<int>>mp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cnt[s[i]-'a']++;
      mp[s[i]-'a'].insert(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
      if(cnt[i]&1) odd++;
    }
    int ans=0;
    if((n&1 && odd == 1)|| ((n&1) == 0 && odd == 0)){
      int left=0,right=n-1;
      while(left < right){
        if(s[left] == s[right]){
          cnt[left]--;
          cnt[right]--;
          mp[s[left]-'a'].erase(left);
          mp[s[right]-'a'].erase(right);
          left++;
          right--;
        }else{
          if(cnt[left]&1 == 0){
            ans++;
            int index = *mp[s[left]-'a'].rbegin();
            mp[s[left]-'a'].erase(index);
            mp[s[right]-'a'].erase(right);
            mp[s[right]-'a'].insert(index);
            swap(s[right],s[index]);
            cnt[left]-=2;
          }else{
            ans++;
            int index = *mp[s[right]-'a'].begin();
            mp[s[right]-'a'].erase(index);
            mp[s[left]-'a'].erase(left);
            mp[s[left]-'a'].insert(index);
            swap(s[left],s[index]);
            cnt[right]-=2;
          }
          left++;
          right--;
        }
      }
    }else{
      // cout<<odd<<" ";
      cout<<"-1\n";
      return;
    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.